# gray scale hover using css and two images

Tags: html, css

I have tried this code but for some reason it's not working for me. I am following this link that was posted. (CSS-Only, using two sets of Images (Grayscale and Colored). Can you tell me why this isn't working for me? I gave my image an id I put in the site in css why isn't this  working? Here is my html &  css code. 
html

```
<li><a href"http://powerfulgirls.com/img/Thumbnail_FGM_bw.jpg<img src="img/Thumbnail_FGM_bw.jpg" id="thumbnail_fgm" alt="blade"</a></li>
```

css

```
    #thumbnail_fgm { 
background: url(http://powerfulgirls.com/img/thumbnail_fgm_bw.jpg);
} 
    #thumbnail_fgm:hover { 
background: url(http://powerfulgirls.com/img/Thumbnail_FGM_bw.jpg);
}
```

thanks. AG

Comment: looks like the image doesn't exist at that address

Comment: Can you post the html for the tags where you have attached these classes.

Comment: In the html code, did you not close your anchor tag or was it a Ctrl C +V error?? :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, when I clicked on http://powerfulgirls.com/img/Thumbnail_FGM_bw.jpg and http://powerfulgirls.com/img/thumbnail_fgm_bw.jpg, I got a 404 error, meaning the server couldn't find the image.

Also you have no # on thumbnail_fgm. When you use # it means id when you use . it means class so you tag that calls the CSS needs to reflect this as well.

Usually when I do background images, I don't pull from external sources. I do it from the directory from the server.  That way I control the image.  In that case you would use a relative  not an absolute URL.

Something like:

```
#thumbnail_fgm { background: url(img/thumbnail_fgm_bw.jpg);}
```

or if the img directory is under the CSS directory

```
#thumbnail_fgm { background: url(../img/thumbnail_fgm_bw.jpg);}
```

or if it's some place else completely I do

```
#thumbnail_fgm { background: url(/<whereever it is>/img/thumbnail_fgm_bw.jpg);}
```